# Condiitonal shell expansion in docker compose file command field

Tags: docker, shell, docker-compose

I need to launch the following command when the container is created

```
npm run test -g $GREP
```

But invoking docker compose as

```
GREP=upload docker compose up playwright
```

It will print the following error

```
invalid interpolation format for services.playwright.command.[]: "${GREP:+-g}". You may need to escape any $ with another $
```

Basically I need to print `-g` when the `GREP` variable is set else none

EDIT: docker compose file `playwright` section

```
  playwright:
    container_name: playwright
    image: playwright:latest
    build:
      context: ./e2e
      dockerfile: Dockerfile
    working_dir: /home/playwright
    command: ['test', '--', '${GREP:+-g}', '${GREP}']
```

EDIT2: dockerfile

```
FROM mcr.microsoft.com/playwright:v1.25.0-focal
USER pwuser
WORKDIR /home/playwright
COPY package.json package-lock.json ./
RUN npm ci
COPY . ./
ENTRYPOINT ["npm", "run"]
CMD ["test"]
```

Comment: can you post your docker-compose.yml?

Comment: @Mihai done, sorry

Answer (score 0):

This is more a shell problem then a docker one so maybe somebody has a prettier solution. However, this example will fix your issue:

```yaml
version: "3.7"

services:
  test:
    image: alpine
    command: sh -c 'if [ ! -z "$VAR" ]; then echo "npm run test -g $VAR"; else echo "npm run test"; fi'
```

```bash
# example with variable set
VAR=somevar docker compose up test
# example with variable not set
docker compose up test
```

Comment: It gives me `npm ERR! Missing script: "sh"`

Comment: Then probably you define an entrypoint as well. Can you also post the Dockerfile as well?

Comment: Done, so the `sh` is appended to the entrypoint?

Comment: In your case, yes. Please see here a very good explanation for it: `https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/builder/#understand-how-cmd-and-entrypoint-interact`. For your case, you can get rid of the ENTRYPOINT and just use command (or the other way round). Just don't mix them unless you get an advantage out of it.

Comment: Even defining `CMD ["npm", "run", "test"]` will print `playwright  | sh: 1: [[: not found` when the container is started

Comment: I am downloading the image to check what's inside. I see it's microsoft so takes a lot of time... In the meantime, I suggest to create a startup script and use that as ENTRYPOINT. In the startup script we can then put all the logic you want. For now just put `npm run test` in start.sh and have ENTRYPOINT ./start.sh

Comment: ok, in the original solution just replace `[[` with `[` and `]]` with `]`. That will work. I updated the solution as well

Comment: What if I want to set multiple ones like `-g "upload wrong" --retries=1`?

Comment: Sorry I have to edit my previous comment: if I run `VAR="upload wrong" docker compose up playwright` it will print `playwright  | sh: 1: [: upload: unexpected operator`

Comment: if your value has spaces, then you have to change the command. I will update the answer